# Qt multiple decoding thread connect to multiple display widgets, performance is low

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals-slots

Here is my code. In `Processor` class, it produces `Frame` object to corresponding `QGLCanvas` object to display. When there are say 5 `Processor` and `QGLCanvas` pair, the program runs smoothly. But when the pair number is above 6, the GUI is not that responsive and the memory consumption is not stable when resizing the widget window.

Probably, the memory consumption issue is that the painting function `paintEvent` in `QGLCanvas` class is not fast enough to process the emitted `Frame`.

**But why the GUI is becoming less responsive (Is it because the unhandled `emit imageReady(frame);`)? The slot function in each `QGLCanvas` object is handled in a parallel way, is that correct? If that is the case, why is it that adding more `Processor + QGLCanvas` makes the GUI less responsive ?**

**And Can anyone give some practical suggestions about how to improve this decoding & displaying logic ?**

For the decoded image, it is 1920x1080 RGB color image.  My machine is i7-4980 and 8GB memory + GT750M graphics card. When the program is running, the cpu consumtion, the gpu consumption and the memory consumption are not full.

```
class Processor: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ConcurrentQueue<std::shared_ptr<std::string>> image_queue_;
    QGLCanvas* widget_;
    Worker* decoder_;
    QThread* decoderThread_;
    static void CALLBACK DecCBFun();
    void DecodeThread();
    void Start();
    void SetWidget(QGLCanvas* widget);

signals:
    void imageReady(std::shared_ptr<Frame> frame);
    void operate();
    void imageString(std::shared_ptr<std::string> data);
};

Processor::Processor()
{

    decoderThread_ = new QThread();
    decoder_ = nullptr;
    widget_ = nullptr;

    decoder_ = new Worker(camera_id_, this);
    decoder_->moveToThread(decoderThread_);
    QObject::connect(decoderThread_, &QThread::finished, decoder_, &QObject::deleteLater);
    QObject::connect(this, &Processor::operate, decoder_, &Worker::Process);
    decoderThread_->start();
}

void Processor::Start()
{
    if(started_ == false)
        emit operate();
}

void Processor::DecodeThread()
{
    while(true)
    {
        std::shared_ptr<std::string> tmp_str;
        image_queue_.pop(tmp_str);

        if(tmp_str->size() == 4 && *(tmp_str) == "stop")
        {
            stop_ = true;
            break;
        }
        QImage tmp_img((unsigned char*)tmp_str->c_str(), 1920, 1080, QImage::Format_RGB888);

        {

            // should add bbox display method
            std::shared_ptr<Frame> frame = std::make_shared<Frame>();
            frame->image = tmp_img;
            emit imageReady(frame);
        }


    }
}


void Processor::SetWidget(QGLCanvas* widget)
{
    widget_ = widget;
    QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(imageReady(std::shared_ptr<Frame>)), widget_, SLOT(ShowImage(std::shared_ptr<Frame>)));
}


class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Worker(Processor* processor) : {processor_ = std::shared_ptr<Processor>(processor);}
    void Stop(){emit finished();}
    ~Worker(){}

private:
    std::shared_ptr<Processor> processor_;

public slots:
    void Process();

signals:
    void finished();
};

void Worker::Process()
{
    processor_->DecodeThread();
}


class QGLCanvas : public QOpenGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QGLCanvas(QWidget* parent = NULL);

    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event);
private:

    std::shared_ptr<Frame> frame_;

public slots:
    void ShowImage(std::shared_ptr<Frame> frame);
};

void QGLCanvas::ShowImage(std::shared_ptr<Frame> frame)
{
    frame_ = frame;
    repaint();
}

void QGLCanvas::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)
{
    p.setRenderHint(QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform, 1);
    p.drawImage(this->rect(), frame_->image);
}


// other part
std::unordered_map<int, std::shared_ptr<Processor>> processors_;
// funtion to load processors_...
std::vector<QGLCanvas* > display_widgets_(processors_.size());
int counter = 0;
for(auto& it:processors_)
{
    it.second->SetWidget(display_widgets_[counter]);
    it.second->Start();
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Could not find what line of code does `image_queue_.push()` and `Processor::DecodeThread()` should have means on waiting on actual image being added otherwise unsure how fast that thread spins and how many times per second it signals. Also no need to use shared pointers like that especially with Qt. You could have just a container of QString and that would not copy the string data unless changed. Also sending `QImage` like that is such. Consider using non-const `QImage::bits()` for deep copy and just sent `QImage` via the signal. Also thread-shared objects cannot be accessed without mutex lock

Comment: @AlexanderVX image_queue_.push is in DecCBFun, which is a camera sdk related function. So I ignored it.  The intel thread building block concurrent_queue struct contains a internal mutex and it will lock the while loop when the queue is empty, the pop operation cannot pop.

Comment: @AlexanderVX sending qstring between different thread will copy the qstring, right? the connection is a qt:queuedconnection type

Comment: An interesting assumption is that we know that SDK? Plus you don't need to check the string length before doing exact comparison of string to string "stop". Also, the image data is a text string? Not text and std::string used for transporting? It is all highly 'unorthodox'. The most suspicious thing is to spin the thread with no means of synchronization to process images. This is not the way it is correctly done. In my OpenCV apps I read the image and then convert it on worker thread and then send QImage out. If I used separate conversion thread I would figure something with condition var out.

Comment: For handling binary buffers in Qt there QByteArray type or you could have used std::vector<char> or quite a few others but unless that was Base64 or similar text-encoded binary you don't use text string.